# Is it possible to refer to a value within the same map on initialization?

Tags: javascript

I was creating a map with constants when I encountered a case that hindered me from referring to a value within the same map on initialization.

Example:

```
const map = {
     PAGE_ID: '<some_string_id_value>',
     URL: 'https://someUrl.com/?pageId=' + this.PAGE_ID
}
```

Now most will probably tell me that "URL" should be a variable since a constant is never-changing, but it got me wondering of why it's not possible to refer to a value within the same map.

Is it due to the map not being fully initialized yet or is it due to something else?

Comment: Nothing TypeScript-specific about this. It's purely according to the ECMAScript specification. In essence: you can't refer to an object that is not yet created.

Comment: So even if it's a part of the same object, it cannot refer to the value until the object is locked in memory?

Comment: You couldn't use `this` anyway to refer to `map` anyway, that's not what `this` means in JavaScript.  You could *write* `map.PAGE_ID` instead, but this also doesn't work for hte reasons mentioned above.  At the time your JS engine needs to evaluate `map.PAGE_ID`, the  `map` variable has no value.  When you have an assignment like `foo = bar` the JS engine has to evaluate `bar` before it can assign it to `foo`.  This doesn't seem like a TS question; maybe re-tag it JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor#displaying_the_constructor_of_an_object) to create a constructor `MyMap` and an object of that type `map`

Code:

```js
const MyMap = function () {
  this.PAGE_ID = '<some_string_id_value>'
  return {
     PAGE_ID: this.PAGE_ID,
     URL: `https://someUrl.com/?pageId=${this.PAGE_ID}`
  }
}

const map = new MyMap()

console.log(map)
```

Comment: But why is the PAGE_ID value only accessible inside an encapsulated environment such as your return statement but not accessible to a member variable within the same literal object? Are the values not processed in a procedural manner when being compiled? Is it because the value is not fully in memory during the initialization process and therefore not accessible?

Answer (score 0):

`this` keyword doesn't operate inside the object literal, it will point to the object that the function is currently running in. You can use getter and setters in this case:

```js
const map = {
     PAGE_ID: '<some_string_id_value>',
     _URL: 'https://someUrl.com/?pageId=',
     get URL() {
         return this._URL + this.PAGE_ID
     },
     set URL(url) {
         this._URL = url
     }
}

console.log(map.URL) // https://someUrl.com/?pageId=<some_string_id_value>
```

Comment: Seems reasonable. Though I can't help to find it both weird and fascinating that I'm not able to access the internal values of previous member values since In my head that value would be processed into memory or some cache-state during the map creation which should allow me to access it directly. But I find it interesting that it is possible to do so long as the actual value is being used in some encapsulated function within the map itself. Be it a return statement or getter/setter. Is it because the member functions are being processed after the actual values during the map initialization?